# Why does Update Manager give me a `Type not known' error with a PPA?

Tags: apt, update-manager, ppa

I got this message when I was using Update Manager:

```
E:Type 'ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu' 
is not known on line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d
/otto-kesselgulasch-gimp-precise.list
```

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

An error has somehow crept into the PPA's sources list file. Let's just delete and re-add the PPA to fix it.

1. Open the terminal with `Ctrl+Alt+T`
2. Type/paste the below,and press Enter -- enter your password if requested:

   ```
   sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/otto-kesselgulasch-gimp-precise.list
   ```
3. Then type/paste:

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository  ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp -y
   ```
4. Finally, type `sudo apt-get update`, wait for it to finish, and exit the Terminal.

Update Manager should now work without any errors.

Comment: Thank u very much.... Now update session started. here is a new problem.
"The action would require the installation of packages from not authenticated sources- details-libopenexr6"   Pls help How can I authenticate libopenexr6.

Comment: @Santhosh, please accept this answer, and create a new one with the details because this (new one) is a totally different problem :)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/156040/73062