# can not authenticate libopenexr6 in update manager

Tags: update-manager

I got this message when I was using update manager

```
The action would require the installation of packages from not authenticated sources- details-libopenexr6
```

Please help , how can I authenticate libopenexr6 ?

Answer (score 1):

Open your terminal and type this:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get -y upgrade
apt-get -y dist-upgrade
```

to get updates .

Regarding to your issue, open your **update manager** and select **settings** option. In settings window at **other software** option make sure that you have selected all PPA's. Then try again.

Comment: Now update everything except runtime files for the OpenEXR image library.. ie  libopenexr6